# How can I get the correct end time of a nohup command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

echo "Starting Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`
nohup ab -n 20000 -c 70 https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/new.jsp &

echo "Ending Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`

#!/bin/sh

set -x

echo "Starting Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`
nohup ab -n 20000 -c 70 https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/new.jsp &

echo "Ending Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`
```

The script above sends 20000 requests to `https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/new.jsp` with a concurrency of 70. I want it to print the start and end of the `nohup` command. However, when I run this, the `Starting Time` and `Ending Time` are both printed at the same moment, just after launching the script.

How can I get the correct end time?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening? Your `nohup` is running in the background so the second date will be printed immediately, is that the problem?

Comment: yes that is the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*background or foreground ?*

If the code you show is full code, I do not see why you run `nohup .. &` simply remove them, when you enter second echo, `ab` program will have end.

If you code is a snipet, just use `wait` before second echo. e.g.

```
echo "Starting Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`
nohup ab -n 20000 -c 70 https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/new.jsp &
## some shell
wait
echo "Ending Time at "`sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no UN@IP 'date'`
```

- see wait in `bash` manual.

Comment: that was full code only. I removed nohup .. & . now it is working fine . Thank you .